# Javascript If else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

```
$(".Arrow44").click(function(event) {
    $("#aca").slideDown();
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function(event) {
    var a = $(event.target).andSelf().parents("#aca");
        if (a.length == 0 && $("#aca").is(":visible")) {
    $("#aca").slideUp();
}
      else $(".Arrow44").click(function(event) {
   $("#aca").slideUp();
}


});
```

I am trying to accomplish an instance so that when I click on the Arrow44 element it will slideUp. But also, If I click it it will slideDown.

Can I accomplish this relatively simple with this code?

Comment: Watch your brackets.  You're missing a `{` after `else` and missing a `});` after the second `slideUp();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".Arrow44").click(function () {
   $("#aca").slideToggle();
   return false; // stop bubbling and prevent default action - remove if not necessary
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to `return false;` in the click handler

Comment: @Phil: I'm not sure if it's needed (can't say for sure without looking at his code), but I added it anyways. Thanks.

Comment: Just going on the `stopPropagation` bit in the OP. Figured it was an anchor or button

Comment: I'm still analyzing the code. It does not seem to slideUp when I click on the original element that would make it slideDown.